# Linear Operator bounded on a basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, a basis $\{e_j\}$ and an injective function $T$ from $\{e_j\}$ to $\mathcal H$ such that $\| T(e_j) \| \leq C$ for all $j$. Can we always extend $T$ to a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal H$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your post to include information on what you have tried so far.

Comment: As in how? It can obviously be done if $\|T(e_j)\|$ are orthogonal. Injectivity does imply independence but I dont know how to proceed with that. Do I also need to include the counter examples I tried? As in why?

Comment: Yes please include your thoughts and the counter examples would be nice. This is your first post on this website, and the convention here is that you include information like this. Otherwise, many users will downvote your post and try to close it, believing that you haven't given it a fair shot. Just giving you a heads up :)

Comment: The counter examples did not work. Thats why I am asking the question. Frankly, I dont care if its "downvoted". You can just give me a hint if you think the answer is trivial.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you I am merely letting you know how to get the most help and best answer you can.

Comment: Anyway, got the example for which the extension cant be done. $T(e_i) = 1/\sqrt{i}\sum_{j = 1}^{i}e_j$. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it may not work!**

**Procedure**

The standard procedure is to first define it on a basis.

Then expanding it linearly to its span.

After checking continuity extending it onto the closure.

*(As it was defined on a basis this will be well-defined and defined on the whole Hilbert space.)*

**Nonexample**

Given the square summable sequences:
$$\ell^2:=\{(x_n)_n:\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|^2<\infty\}$$
Choose the canonical basis:
$$\varepsilon_n:=(0,\ldots,1,0,\ldots)$$
Define an operator by:
$$T\varepsilon_n:=\varepsilon_n+\varepsilon_0:\quad\|T\varepsilon_n\|\leq2$$
Then one has:
$$\varphi:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}\varepsilon_n:\quad\|T\varphi\|^2:=\|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}T\varepsilon_n\|^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n^2}-1+\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}+1\right)^2=\infty$$
*(Formally one has to do these latter steps separately.)*