# When $\|T(b)\|\le M\|b\|$ for each vector from a basis implies that $T$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

A linear operator $T\colon X\to Y$ between linear normed spaces is bounded if there exists a constant $M$ such that $$\|Tx\| \le M\|x\|\tag{*}$$ holds for *every* $x\in X$. Are there some situations when it is sufficient to verify that this condition is true for elements from some [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis) $B$?

Is there characterization of normed spaces here validity of $(*)$ for some Hamel basis implies boundedness? Are there at least some sufficient conditions? Is situation easier in Banach spaces? Can we say something at least for $Y=\mathbb R, \mathbb C$?

Or are there perhaps no pairs $(X,B)$ such that boundedness on $B$ implies boundedness on $X$?

My feeling about this question is that this might be somehow related to the "shape" of the unit ball. But I guess that convexity of unit ball is probably not enough.

---

This basically arose from a rather elementary discussion about a linear operator defined on $X=c_{00}$. (The space of sequences which have only finitely many non-zero terms with the sup norm. In this can write down an explicit basis $e^{(i)}=(0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ and in the conversation I got an impression that the other person thinks that it suffices to verify $(*)$ for these vectors. I corrected them and said that we need to check this for each $x\in X$ - or at least for all elements of the unit ball - if we follow the definition they've learned. But I realized that the question whether this work at least sometimes might be quite complicated.)

I searched a bit to see whether similar question has been posted here in the past. I only found this question, which deals with [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) rather than Hamel basis: [Linear Operator bounded on a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153237).

Answer (score 10):

I think for the case $T:\ell^2\to\mathbb R$ this is not possible.

First, we choose a Hamel basis
$\{e_n : n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{f_i : i\in I\}$,
where $e_n$ are the (standard, orthogonal) unit vectors.

Now we can define $T$ via
$$
  T e_n = 1
  \\
  T f_i = 0
$$

and accordingly on linear combinations of these.

Now $\| Tx \| \leq  \|x\|$
holds for this basis.
On the other hand, it can be seen that $T$ is unbounded:
Indeed, for $x_n := e_1+\dots+e_n$
we have $\| x_n \|=\sqrt{n}$,
but $T x_n = n$, so
$\frac1{\| x_n \|} Tx_n = \sqrt{n} \to \infty$.

Comment: Why is it true that $\|x_n\| = \sqrt n$?

Comment: Because $e_n$ are orthogonal unit vectors. If you calculate the $2$-norm, you get $\|x_n\|= \|(1,1,\dots,1)\| = \sqrt{1+1+\cdots+1} = \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @sas I added the word "orthogonal" in the answer, to clarify.

Comment: But Hamel basis cannot be orthogonal in infinite dimensions. Nvm, got it, only countable part here is orthonormal.

Answer (score 8):

To extend supinf's result, in Banach spaces this is impossible: It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79184/at-most-finitely-many-hamel-coordinate-functionals-are-continuous-different?noredirect=1&lq=1) that for every Hamel basis of them $B=\{b_i: i\in I\}$, at most finitely many of the coordinate functionals are bounded. On the other hand each coordinate functional $b_i^{\#}$ is bounded on $B$, as for $i\neq j$, $b_i^{\#}(b_j)=0 \leq \|b_j\|$ and $b_i^{\#}(b_i)=1 \leq \frac{1}{\|b_i\|}\|b_i\|$, so each $b_i^{\#}$ is bounded on the base with a constant $M_i=\frac{1}{\|b_i\|}$.

Comment: For benefit of other users, I'll add links to some posts about the claim concerning coordinate functionals: [Are the coordinate functions of a Hamel basis for an infinite dimensional Banach space discontinuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33282) and [At most finitely many (Hamel) coordinate functionals are continuous - different proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79184).

Comment: BTW this shows that this problem is much less interesting that I thought - since your answer shows that this cannot work in complete spaces.